# Visual Studio linker error when template class meets __declspec(import)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

This has started with a seemingly minor problem I've encountered when I was integrating my small exception handling library into a code base consisting of ~200 Visual C++ projects in a single Visual Studio solution.

I've got a linker problem expressed by a message like this

```
3>B_Utils.lib(B_Utils.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>::ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$ExceptionBase@Vruntime_error@std@@@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in TranslationUnit_2.obj
3>B_Utils.lib(B_Utils.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __cdecl ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>::~ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>(void)" (??1?$ExceptionBase@Vruntime_error@std@@@@UEAA@XZ) already defined in TranslationUnit_2.obj
3>B_Utils.lib(B_Utils.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>::ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>(class ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error> const &)" (??0?$ExceptionBase@Vruntime_error@std@@@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z) already defined in TranslationUnit_2.obj
```

At first glance, it looked as yet another typical problem that can be solved with a typical advice "try changing the order of #include files" or "move implementation out of the header file", but it wasn't.

I've explored a number of similarly related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958084/linker-errors-already-defined) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915037/linker-error-already-defined), but none of them fits my case. At least, the proposed recipes don't help with my issue.

Furthermore, a long ago people in our company have encountered another problem related to Visual Studio linker during migration to VS2010, which turned out to be a linker bug, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987171/inherit-from-stdstring-without-npos-problems-in-dlls). Anyway, neither that one matched my scenario.

So this tiny issue ended up with a whole mini-research. You may find the details and the toy example that reproduces the problem [here at github](https://github.com/4sily/VisualStudioLinkerIssue). In the meantime, I'll try to describe the situation below as briefly as possible.

---

The key ingredients that lead to the build failure are:

1. 3 projects (let's name them A,B,C) with dependency graph like this: B->A, C->B, C->A.
2. In project A we define a template class. It gets intantiated within the header of that project A.
3. DLL-exported class in project B which inherits from the same intantiation of template class from 2).
4. Project C with **at least two** tranlation units, at least one of them includes both 2) and 3).

In the code, it looks like this:

**A_SDK**:

```
(ExceptionBase.h)
template<typename T>
class ExceptionBase;
--
(foo.h)
#include "ExceptionBase.h"
inline void foo() // same effect would be with template<typename T> void foo()
{
    throw ExceptionBase<std::runtime_error>("Problem");
}
```

**B_Utils**:

```
(Error.h)
#include "ExceptionBase.h"
#if defined(B_EXPORTS)
#define _B_UTILS_EXPORTS_CLASS      __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define _B_UTILS_EXPORTS_CLASS      __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct _B_UTILS_EXPORTS_CLASS Error : public ExceptionBase<std::runtime_error>
{ Error(std::string&& s); } // ctor definition is in *.cpp file
```

**C_Client**:

```
(TranslationUnit_1.cpp)
#include "A_SDK/foo.h"
#include "B_Utils/Error.h"      // !!! Comment this line --> Build succeeds
void TranslationUnit_1() { 
  foo();                        // !!! Comment this line --> Build succeeds
}
(TranslationUnit_2.cpp)
#include "A_SDK/foo.h"
void TranslationUnit_2() {
  foo();                        // !!! Comment this line --> Build succeeds
}
```

Pay attention to those lines marked with `// !!!`. Commenting **any** of them will make the build successful. As mentioned above, full sources are available [at github](https://github.com/4sily/VisualStudioLinkerIssue).

Could anyone explain what is going wrong here?
Essentially, I'd like to understand:

- Am I going against some rule here?
- or is it Visual Studio linker issue?

---

P.S. There is a workaround that helped me to advance with my work. See [github's README](https://github.com/4sily/VisualStudioLinkerIssue) for details. However, the root cause of the problem remains unclear to me.

Comment: My working hypothesis is the following. When I export the whole type via `struct _B_UTILS_EXPORTS_CLASS Error : public ExceptionBase<std::runtime_error>`, the template instantiation `ExceptionBase<std::runtime_error>` gets exported too. In the latter case, when I only export ctor: `_B_UTILS_EXPORTS_CLASS Error()` - the template instantiation is not exported, hence the linker sees only one symbol in **C_Client**. What I don't understand: why isn't it able to merge the symbols in the former case? Just like it happens e.g. for static libraries.

Comment: Your github solution is missing some files - Roulette*, Profile*.

Comment: @ZDF true, I made some changes in VS2017 and forgot to update VS2013 projects. Now it's fine again. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: `MakeThingsGood.h`: _"plain 'throw' will lead to linker error as well"_ - Not true.

Comment: @ZDF well, I've just checked out the repo and tried it out. If I replace std::throw_with_nested with plain throw, I do get the following error on both VS2013 and VS2017: `3>B_Utils.lib(B_Utils.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>::ExceptionBase<class std::runtime_error>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$ExceptionBase@Vruntime_error@std@@@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in TranslationUnit_2.obj`. Don't you have the same?

Comment: _"Don't you have the same?"_ It compiles fine. I'm running VS 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Answer (score 3):

I dug a bit at your solution and have grown to believe too it is a compiler bug. It can be narrowed down to a much smaller repro, with only 2 binaries and zero standard library dependencies - and you can inspect it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8m18mj2w1wqcvoa/VisualStudioLinkerIssue-master%20-%20trimmed.rar?dl=0).

The critical code that seems to cause the mayhem is this -

```
struct BaseWithVirtual
{
    virtual void what() {}       // !!! make this non-virtual --> Build succeeds
};
    
template<typename dummy>
struct ExceptionBase : public BaseWithVirtual  {};

struct ExceptionChild : public  ExceptionBase<int> {};

inline void ThrowChild()
{
    ExceptionChild up;
    throw up;   // !!! comment this --> Build succeeds
}
```

This is ThrowChild.h in the dropbox link, and the original equivalents are spread across multiple files in the standard library - mostly < exception>.

Please update here if and when they resolve this.

---

Update:
3 years after reporting, [MS resolved it (rightfully) as not a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80966/linker-error-when-template-class-meets-declspecimp.html).  Their full answer is dumped here, since many times in the past I settled for a link and it went dead.

> dllimport/dllexport on a derived class needs to implicitly mark the
> base class as dllimport/dllexport, too. However, this can introduce
> ODR (one definition rule) violation as seen in your repro.
>
> In project 'B_Utils', 'ExceptionBase' is implicitly marked as
> dllimport/dllexport because its derived class 'Error' is marked as
> dllimport/dllexport.
>
> In project 'C_Client', the same class is not inherited and isn't
> marked as dllimport/dllexport.
>
> This means when you link the two projects together you end up having
> two definitions of the same class and this ODR violation causes the
> linker error because one of its member (the copy consructor) is
> considered as a real function in 'C_Client' and an imported function
> in 'B_Utils'.
>
> To avoid the potential ODR violation, it is better to explicitly mark
> the base class as dllimport/dllexport too.
>
> This means it can be challenging to dllexport a class which derives
> from a class from the standard library. In this case, you may need to
> consider using other approaches.
>
> Or you can add this to project 'C_Client' to avoid the ODR violation:
>
> struct _B_UTILS_EXPORTS_CLASS DummyClassToAvoidORDViolation : public
> ExceptionBase {};

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks a lot for your efforts!

Comment: The quoted code is the essence behind 'std::throw_with_nested(ExceptionBase<std::runtime_error>("Cannot build T"));'  I also looked at dumpbin /SYMBOLS on TranslationUint_1.obj with and without some modifications (eg virtual what() ), and the diff in contained symbols is unexplainable. It has to be a compiler bug.

Comment: It's also quite interesting that your repro-case fails in Debug x64, while Release x64 builds fine (at least, that's what I observe on my machine). So maybe there is even more than 1 bug.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio support team triaged this issue, and as a result they filed a bug. Investigation is ongoing, details can be seen [on Visual Studio forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80966/linker-error-when-template-class-meets-declspecimp.html).
I'll update this answer once I get further feedback from them.

---

**P.S.**: Whether this will be recognized as a linker bug or not, I'd like to state that exporting complex C++ interfaces from DLL's is not really a good practice in general. Unfortunately I cannot change it in the codebase I'm working with.

Personally, for architecture based on DLL plugins I would recommend either using some marshalling layer (like COM) or explicitly design interfaces according to "Hourglass principle". Here is [a great talk from CppCon 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVYdHDm0q6Y) that explains what that is.